# The type or namespace does not exist when compiling for ARM and in Release mode - UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

This is extremly frustrating as I've spent the last couple of ways working on a way to encrypt/decrypt some data without having to use a `salt` key and found the `Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection` which worked fine but wasn't without it's problems so now that all my issues were sorted, I decided to compile it as `ARM` and in `Release` mode but now I'm getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the
namespace 'Windows' are you missing an assembly reference?
```

The following `Namespace` are being highlighted as problematic the second I go from `Debug` to `Release` mode:

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
```

This is obviously a major problem as now I can't release my app!

Anyone has got any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1:**

Actually, it doesn't look like it has anything to do with `ARM` as I've just tried it with `x86` and `x64` and the problem remains!

**UPDATE-2:**

What I don't understand is that I'm currently looking at Microsoft sample called `EnterpriseDataProtection` and this compiles fine in `Release` mode and I can see the following `Namespace`:

```
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Security.EnterpriseData;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
```

and they are not highlighted as problematic and the app compiles fine!

I've just spotted something odd. When I check the references for the 2 extension (Mobile & Desktop) from my project, these are listed as follows:

```
Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP
Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP
```

yet in the `EnterpriseDataProtection` solution, they are listed as:

```
Microsoft Desktop Extension SDK for Universal App Platform
Microsoft Mobile Extension SDK for Universal App Platform
```

Why the different names?

Taking the `Desktop` one from the `EnterpriseDataProtection` Solution, it provides the following information:

```
(Name): Microsoft Desktop Extension SDK for Universal App Platform
File Type: SDK
Identity: WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10240.0
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension
      SDKs\WindowsDesktop\10.0.10240.0\
Resolved: True
Version: 10.0.10240.0
```

When I check the `Desktop` one in my project, it has the following information:

```
(Name): Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP
File Type: SDK
Identity: WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.10240.0
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension
      SDKs\WindowsDesktop\10.0.10240.0\
Resolved: True
Version: 10.0.10240.0
```

The location appears to be identical so you'd think I should be ok, but why the different names??

Don't know if the above is of any use, but I thought I'd mention it.

**UPDATE-3:**

This is getting more ridiculous by the minute!!! I've just removed both extensions (Mobile & Desktop) and I removed a test `Console` application from my solution as I noticed it was also using this and throwing the same errors and as I didn't need it, I removed it!

I tried to compile and it worked! So I went ahead and re-added the 2 extensions to check if they were the cause of the problem but now I'm getting a totally new error:

```
An assembly with the same simple name
'Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract' has already been imported.
Try removing one of the references (e.g. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\10\References\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract\1.0.0.0
\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd') or sign them to 
enable side-by-side.
```

I've removed the extensions once again and the app is now compiling fine again!!

What is going on??? The main thing is that it is compiling now.

I've just re-added my console app to my solution and the errors are back and only now did I notice when expending the `Project` column that it was coming from my `Console` application instead of my `UWP` app. Unfortunately, I'm using the same class names in both app and didn't pay attention to the actual project!

I can only apologises and hope I didn't cause you to waste to much time on this!

On another note, but not important to me right now, is why is `Windows.Security` failing on a `Console` application when in `Release` mode.

Again, sorry and thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: Try adding the Mobile and Desktop extension

Comment: @AbsoluteSith I just did. I will try the latest version i.e. 10.0.10586 instead of 10.0.10240 and see how I get on but note that with 10.0.10240, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: So this is happening only in Release mode?

Comment: correct. I've just tried with 10.0.10586 and it made no difference. Oh, one sec. I didn't spot that you mention to add the Desktop as well. I didn't have that. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Nope! Even when including `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP`, it made no difference.

Comment: Are you building using .Net Native Configuration?

Comment: @CarbineCoder I've just checked and my 'Compile with .NET Native tool chain' is selected.

Comment: If you haven't tried already. See if you can uncheck  'Compile with .NET Native tool chain' and compile.

Comment: @CarbineCoder It made no difference unfortunately. Note that I've updated my question with more info. In the Microsoft sample 'EnterpriseDataProtection', the `Compile with .NET Navite tool chain` is selected.

Comment: @CarbineCoder - Problem sorted. Check out the update... So sorry!

Comment: @AbsoluteSith - Thanks again for the help and apologies for the cockup! Thanks.